# AngularJS - Puting module in separate file

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am currently trying to get AngularJS working with Node, but for some reason as soon as I move the script to a separate file, I get the error "[Error: Injector Modulerr] Failed to instantiate module due to[...]".

I have done this 50 times before and have no idea why I am facing the problem now.

In my RESTful Node API I have 2 "wild card"-routes; '/*' and '/admin*'.

When I am rendering a index.html in my '/*'-route Angular is working fine, but when I am trying to do the same within my '/admin*' I seem to get the error mentioned above.

```
<!-- jQuery 3.1.1 -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS 1.5.8 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

<!-- App -->
<script>
    var app = angular.module('rs-admin', [])
</script>
```

Comment: The module in the other file have the same name? In this case check if you are using `angular.module('rs-admin', [])` again instead of `angular.module('rs-admin')`.

Comment: In the other file I have this code, var app = angular.module('rs-admin', []), and I am including the file with "<script src="js/app.hs"></script>

Comment: From [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module): "Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module."

Comment: If I name the Angular Modules the same, for the different index-files, it works fine. Doesn't feel right thou.

Comment: If you're new to all this, don't use Angular in conjunction with server-side MVC. By that I mean, if you're gonna use Angular, don't render stuff on the server. Build a "Single Page Application" instead, use express.static to expose all the html/css/js (Angular included). Your server should only provide JSON APIs then

Comment: I am building a SPA, theres now way I can utlilize AngularJS if I'm not rendering a file from Node, unless I am running my app on a separate server. However, that's not the problem I'm currently facing.

Comment: Open your browser developer tool (F12 for chrome). Checkout the site's Sources. See the behavior when you're switching pages between routes in an MVC application

Comment: My wish was that I could separate my editor, from my website. By using two separate angular modules, meaning I can split my entire project to two separate projects. I guess I'll have to stick with one SPA

Comment: SPA require no rendering on the server. Server should not acknowledge anything about the view

Comment: That's totally depending on how you implement it. I am running my SPA on my node server, meaning I wont need a separate server to run it.

Comment: It might be valuable to post more code. There's nothing in the snippet provided that can be debugged.

Comment: Check out this gist... Nope, no separate server, you can serve the HTML contents on the same server, just no rendering
https://gist.github.com/rocketspacer/15eae2299edb92d89b2bf8c2a74650cc

Comment: Rendering is resolving your data on to an HTML file and return that HTML to client, which is traditional on MVC website.
Server for SPA however only return data (JSON, Binary, etc). How you put that data to an HTML page is totally abstract to the server